# File upload (.pdf) with PHP and mySQL not working,

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, upload

Okay, so i am doing this project which is a file repository and right now i am trying to make the functionality of uploading a file for example a .pdf and i have followed the following guide http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

But i am still having the following problems: The page keeps loading for eternity.When i go check my database the title and stuff is stored but the  format, size and content is just stay as 0 as the values.

So i am useing the MVC file system.

My table consist of the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FoldersFiles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Tag` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `FileSize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The size is calculated in MD',
  `UploadedDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LastEditDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Format` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Content` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `UserID` (`UserID`,`ParentID`),
  KEY `ParentID` (`ParentID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=83 ;
```

And my View that allows the user to upload a new file:

```
<form method="post" class="basic-frm" id="newFolder" action="../Controller/folders.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
            <label>
                <span>Title:</span>
                <input id="title"  type="text" name="filetitle"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Description:</span>
                <input id="description" type="text" name="filedescription"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Tag:</span>
                <input id="tag" type="text" name="filetag" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="button"/>
            </label>
        </form>
```

And my controller is the following :

```
if ((isset($_POST['filetitle']))   && (isset($_POST['filedescription'])) && (isset($_POST['filetag']))  && (isset($_FILES['file'])))
    {
        $title = $_POST['filetitle'];
        $description = $_POST['filedescription'];
        $tag = $_POST['filetag'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $format = $_FILES['file']['type'];

        $clean = array();

        #checking if the data is clean.
        if((ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '',$title))) && (ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '',$description))) && (ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", "-"), '',$tag))))
        {
            $clean['title'] = $title;
            $clean['description'] = $description;
            $clean['tag'] = $tag;
        }


        if((isset($clean['title'])) && (isset($clean['description'])) && (isset($clean['tag'])))
        {
            $fp = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, filesize($fileTmpName));
            $content = addslashes($content);
            fclose($fp);

            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
            }

            require_once('../Model/Folder.php');
            $folder = new Folder();

            if(!isset($_SESSION['parentID']))
            {
                $rootID = $folder->getRoot($_SESSION['userID']);
            }
            else
            {
                $rootID = $_SESSION['parentID'];
            }
            $folder->setInfo($_SESSION['userID'],$clean['title'],$clean['description'],$clean['tag'],$rootID,$size,$format,$content);
            header('Location: ../View/folders.php');
            var_dump($clean);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong data";
        }
    }
```

The setInfo method :

```
public function setInfo($userID,$title,$description,$tags,$parentID,$fileSize,$format,$content)
        {
            $this->userID=$userID;
            $this->title= $title;
            $this->description = $description;
            $this->tag = $tags;
            $this->format = $format;
            $this->fileSize = $fileSize;
            $this->content = $content;

            $dbh = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->dbUser,$this->dbpassword);

            $insertQuery = <<<'insertQuery'
INSERT INTO `FoldersFiles` (`Title`,`Description`,`Tag`,`UserID`,`ParentID`,`LastEditDate`,`FileSize`,`Format`,`Content`)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
insertQuery;

            $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
            $time = date($dateFormat);

            $sth = $dbh->prepare($insertQuery);
            $sth->execute(array($title,$description,$tags,$userID,$parentID,$time,$fileSize,$format,$content));
        }

        public function getInfo($userID, $parentId )
        {
            $this->userID = $userID;

            $dbh = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->dbUser,$this->dbpassword);
            $selectQuery = <<<'selectQuery'
SELECT * FROM `FoldersFiles` WHERE `userID` = ? AND `ParentID` = ?
selectQuery;

            $sth = $dbh->prepare($selectQuery);
            $sth->execute(array($userID,$parentId));
            $result =  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
```

So the problem again is when i try to upload a file it just keeps loading for ever and after i go to phpmyadmin to check my data the title and description is inserted but Filze size and content and format stay 0.

Comment: Put some error processing after each of the PDO statement, especially the one storing the blob

Comment: I have already tried that since it returns no error and it makes sense since it is insert the other values normal.

Comment: Have you checked your MySQL error log. Have you worked out where it is hanging

Comment: I will try to do that, give me a second need to figure out how to do it on Ubuntu :)

Comment: Don't bother. Mysql probably not lagging behind. It's an insert. Login on your ubuntu a run 'top' while inserting. You'll see PHP is having a hard time. An insert is light and should bring no stress on a single one.

Comment: What do you suggest that i do then, to figure out the problem i mean.

Comment: You have to work out where the hang is occuring or you are not going to know where/what to fix

Answer (score 0):

I PHP hangs and your using fread, it's most probably the cause of the problem. If I'd have to guess there is something wrong with the file or it's data (not corrupted, but maybe just not there).

Try to make another script without the whole MVC and try to read it from the server directory instead of from FILES.

If that works extend it with your form and a page request.

If that works do a partial rebuild of your script.

It might be the long way around, but it always works for debugging. Cause if you want to find the problem eliminate the rest.

Comment: Okay i will try and do that!

Comment: Good luck my man, let us know if you came any closer. Like stated, it's probably fread. Do a google search on it. It is kinda dodgy in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the suggest gonna get cracking now :) might take me a while since i am still learning php.

Comment: Let us know if you have specific questions. I might be able to assist

Comment: Okay, i wanted to ask you what do you mean by "read from the server directory instead from FILES"

Comment: Well, you are uploading the file through a web page now. But try to the file on the server and read it from local storage. This eliminates the file upload and will assure you of the fact that that the file is indeed there.

Comment: So i trid to do the following 

  `code`<?php
    $current_dir ="/home/steve/Desktop/test.txt";
    $file = basename($current_dir);
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $fp = fopen($path.$current_dir, 'r');

    $myfile = "/test.txt";
    while(!feof($myfile))
    {
        $content = fgets($fp,999);
        echo $content;
    }

And it takes a while to load but doesnt read anything form the file.And i do have data in the file

Comment: Ok, unless your AMMPS's or MAMP's (or whatever you're using) www folder is in your home folder, this will not work. Put the file in the www directory of your website and read it from there. Just like an image, get my drift?

Comment: Yes, I will try it when i get home since i have to go for an urgent arrent now :/ Ill keep you posted and keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need/want to upload the content to the database?  I am currently working on an upload feature with audio files, and to avoid sql issues with large files we are storing the filename in a db and storing the actual file on the filesystem, which is later served via php.

```
        if((isset($clean['title'])) && (isset($clean['description'])) && (isset($clean['tag'])))
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $finalLocation)){
            //Handle success
        }else{
            //Handle failure
        }
```

If you must upload to the db. have you put a break point right before the sql query to verify the variables $filesize, $content, and $format contain what you expect?

Comment: mmm I guess that could work aswell and then in the database i will store the path of the folder? And then i use the fread to read the contents of the file?

Comment: Thats the general idea.  Store the file name in the db (example: "user_id + unix_timestamp.pdf").  When serving the pdf, query for the filename, concatenate > $filePath.$filename., then serve with fread

Comment: I will give it a shot later today cause i need to do a file repositry that will readm sot file extensetions like pdf txt and doc

Answer (score 0):

So i mange to fix the problem with was with some wrong code, but the weird thing is that it still keeps crashing when i upload a pdf other formats are just fine!

```
if((ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '',$title))) && (ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '',$description))) && (ctype_alnum(str_replace(array(' ', "'", "-"), '',$tag))))
            {
                $clean['title'] = $title;
                $clean['description'] = $description;
                $clean['tag'] = $tag;
            }

            if((isset($clean['title'])) && (isset($clean['description'])) && (isset($clean['tag'])))
            {
                require_once('../Model/Folder.php');
                $folder = new Folder();

                if(isset($rootID))
                {
                    $rootID = $folder->getRoot($_SESSION['userID']);
                }

                if((isset($_FILES['uploadFile'])) && $_FILES['uploadFile']['size']  > 0)
                {
                    $tmpFileName  = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
                    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'];
                    $fileType = $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];

                    $fp      = fopen($tmpFileName, 'r');
                    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpFileName));
                    $content = addslashes($content);
                    fclose($fp);
                }

                $folder->setInfo($_SESSION['userID'],$clean['title'],$clean['description'],$clean['tag'],$rootID,$fileSize,$fileType,$content);
                header('Location: ../View/folders.php');
            }'
```

I had something wrong with the code with the supergoabal $_FILES